# Class change of button via jquery is changed back, when clicking another button from same class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick, background-color

I want to change the color of the buttons on my white ('btn-secondary') pagination from bootstrap to yellow ('btn-warning'), when they are clicked.
This works with my code below, but If I click the next button on the same pagination, the previously clicked button turns to the previous color.

The HTML:

```
<button class="showAufgabe btn btn-secondary btn-sm">01</button>
<button class="showAufgabe btn btn-secondary btn-sm">02</button>
...
<button class="showAufgabe btn btn-secondary btn-sm">39</button>
<button class="showAufgabe btn btn-secondary btn-sm">40</button>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showAufgabe = $('.showAufgabe');
    $(document).on('click', showAufgabe, clickedAufgabe);

    function clickedAufgabe() {
        $(this).addClass('btn-warning').removeClass('btn-secondary');
    }
});
```

Thank you in advance! :-)

Here's a gif of how it looks: 
[Simulation.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2tHv.gif)

I want the first one to stay yellow!

Comment: $('.showAufgabe') represents all the btn having this class -- so just use $(this) to apply changes only to the clicked btn

Comment: I'm not quite shure I get what you mean ...

Comment: I edited my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting `.showAufgabe` to a variable, you are actually selecting all elements that share that same class name - in this case all buttons.

```
var showAufgabe = $('.showAufgabe');
```

Instead you could call `$(this)` when a button is clicked within your function. It would then toggle `.btn-warning` only on that specific button.

```js
$(".showAufgabe").on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('btn-warning');
});
```

```css
.btn-warning {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="showAufgabe btn btn-secondary btn-sm">01</button>
<button class="showAufgabe btn btn-secondary btn-sm">02</button>
...
<button class="showAufgabe btn btn-secondary btn-sm">39</button>
<button class="showAufgabe btn btn-secondary btn-sm">40</button>
```

***Side note:*** it may depend on your specific requirement, but you wouldn't have to remove the previous class, as `.btn-warning` appears further down in the bootstrap style sheet than `.btn-secondary`, applying it to the button class would overwrite the previous style applied via `.btn-secondary`.

Comment: @themd91 does this achieve what you intended?

Comment: yes it does in the stricter sense! but my script code for the pagination interferes with it and I didn't know that. I will edit my post in a few minutes..

Comment: Sorry, I have the problem! I have a php-for-loop which creates 40 exercises including all of the buttons for each step of the for loop. Therefore every time I click one button, another set of my pagination-html is shown and therefore it doesn't work! So your code achieved what I intended, thanks a lot @Liondedan

Comment: @themd91 great! Good luck with the rest of the build

Answer (score 0):

Just as someone commented, use `$(this)` to target only the button that has been clicked.

like so:

```
$('.showAufegabe.btn-secondary').click( function () {
    $(this).addClass('btn-warning').removeClass('btn-secondary');    
});


$('.showAufegabe.btn-warning').click( function () {
    $(this).addClass('btn-secondary').removeClass('btn-warning');    
});
```